# JArray - search for an object by key name

Tags: c#, json

I have an object of type JArray, which contains a list of json objects. The JArray looks like:

```
JArray jarray = [{"Key1":"v1"}, {"Key2":"v2"}, {"Key3":"v3"}]
```

Now I want to retrieve an element from jarray such that the element contains a given key name, for instance, get the element whose keyname is `Key2` instead of `Key1` or `Key3`. How can I achieve it under the circumstance that the element may not always be in the same place in the jarray so that I cannot access it by index?

Comment: Is using an actual class representation of your data an option?

Answer (score 8):

Use `Newtonsoft.Json.Linq` in package `Newtonsoft.Json` to do so:

```
private static JToken[] SearchKey(JArray jarray, string key, bool ignoreCase)
{
    return jarray.Where(x => x is JObject ? ((JObject)x).ContainsKey(key) : false).ToArray();
}
```

In more recent versions of C# you can also shorten it a bit using:

```
private static JToken[] SearchKey(JArray jarray, string key, bool ignoreCase)
{
    return jarray.Where(x => x is JObject y && y.ContainsKey(key)).ToArray();
}
```

Comment: Just a note that in recent versions of C# you can do `x is JObject y && y.ContainsKey(key)`.

Comment: Cool! Just using older compiler so don't want to put code with syntax errors. Please feel free to modify code with newer syntax.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Linq's where clause to query the JArray.  This code filters the results to items that have "Key1" and have a non-null value.

```
using System.Linq;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

JArray jarray = JArray.Parse("[{ \"Key1\":\"v1\"}, { \"Key2\":\"v2\"}, { \"Key3\":\"v3\"}]");
var result = jarray.Where(v => v["Key1"] != null).ToList();
```